# How to config mergerfs sort files by type and save them to specified physical disks

Tags: ubuntu

I have two disks:

disk(ssd) /dev/sdb is mounted to /mnt/sdb and it  is used to save *txt and *.json file.

disk(hdd) /dev/sdc is mounted to /mnt/sdc and it  is used to save any other files.

mergerfs mounts /mnt/sdb and /mnt/sdc to /mnt/logs.

my application directly access /mnt/logs directory. In case my app write a *.txt file or *.json file, file saves on /dev/sdb physically.

How to make this happen automatically through a mergerfs config settings?

The app randomly create files, then check the file locations, should be like this:

`/mnt/logs/aaa.txt is on /dev/sdb. /mnt/logs/bbb.json is on /dev/sdb. /mnt/logs/ccc.bin is on /dev/sdc.`

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this directly in mergerfs. Why not create the file by writing to /mnt/sdb/ to control what disk it ends up on?

Comment: Thanks @NickODell. Directly writing to /mnt/sdb/ is a practical solution, also it is very safe. I had this special requirement just because the app is not made by me and I would like to avoid changing the app. If mergerfs is not capable to support, I have to update the app.